# Uniform Convergence $\sum \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Analyze the uniform convergence of the following series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$$

My attempt- This converges absolutely and uniformly for $(-\infty,\delta]\bigcup[\delta,\infty)$ using Weierstrass Mn Test with $$M_n= \frac{1}{\delta n^2}$$

I am not able to make any conclusions for $(-\delta, \delta)$. I tried looking [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uhkjgwxpre) and nothing weird is hapenning at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\sqrt{n}|x|\leq \frac{1+nx^2}{2} $ we have that $$|\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}|\leq\frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$
Which by Weierstrass test gives us uniform convergence, since $\sum \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$ is convergent